# How to fix the CORS and unblock the load of my JS File?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS Web and I wanted to add import `import { hash } from "crypto";` but I get an error telling me this:

> Access to script at '*js file here*' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for
> protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave,
> chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: You can't use `import { hash } from "crypto";` in browser code. Either use the full URL to an ES6 module or use a bundler, like Webpack or Parcel.

Comment: What did you mean by "You can't use import in browner code" ?

Comment: Browser code is evaluated in the browser on the client's computer. There is no `crypto`. The client doesn't know, what this means. You have to use a complete URL to import ES6 modules.

Comment: So how i import ES6 modules with urls?

Comment: _"You have to use a complete URL to import ES6 modules."_ `import { hash } from "complete/URL/to/crypto";` and you need a script tag with `type="module"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules